# Why isn't my SVG centering with the group?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am able to load a svg and two textboxes into a fabric canvas with the text below the svg.
However, when I try to group all three of these to center the group, I am unable to group the svg with the two textboxes. The two textboxes group together and center vertically but the SVG stays separate.

```
var sign = new fabric.Canvas('canvas_0');

sign.backgroundColor = "green";

var w = 633;
var h = 291;
var fontSize = w / 12;

var vtop = 0;
var mainText = new fabric.Textbox("Testing", {
    top: vtop,
    fontSize: fontSize,
    width: Number(w),
    textAlign: "center",
    fill: "red",
});

vtop += mainText.calcTextHeight();

var subText = new fabric.Textbox("Subtext", {
    top: vtop,
    fontSize: fontSize/2,
    width: Number(w),
    textAlign: "center",
    fill: "red",
});

var svgURL = '/assets/example.svg';
var svgVar;
var group = new fabric.Group([], {});
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(svgURL, function(objects) {
    svgVar = objects[0].set({
        top: 0,
        fill: "blue"
    });
    svgVar.scaleToWidth(w/3);
    svgVar.scaleToHeight(h/3);
    svgVar.setCoords();
    sign.add(svgVar);
    svgVar.centerH();
});

sign.add(mainText);
sign.add(subText);

var objs = sign.getObjects();
var group = new fabric.Group(objs);
sign.centerObject(group);
sign.add(group);
sign.renderAll();
```

Output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyLaV.png)

Expected Output:
Both SVG and textbox should be in the same group and be centered vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Can you share the code of the svg

Comment: Yeah here is the svg code
`<svg width="2048" height="2048" viewBox="0 0 2048 2048" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M1034.7 289C1363.45 289 1641.83 504.564 1736.14 802.018H1032.08V802.142C910.443 803.544 812.268 902.56 812.268 1024.5C812.268 1147.31 911.855 1246.87 1034.7 1246.87C1145.98 1246.87 1238.17 1165.19 1254.55 1058.53H1601.15L1748 1205.34C1667.39 1524.11 1378.6 1760 1034.7 1760C628.385 1760 299 1430.71 299 1024.5C299 618.295 628.385 289 1034.7 289Z" fill="#F3B235"/>
</svg>`